# Unable to create new team project in TFS - Tf30177: Team Project Creation Failed

Tags: tfs

I am trying to create a new team project in VS 2012 using agile template - 'MSF for Agile Software Development 6.2'. We use VS2012 connected to TFS 2012 (TFS databse is sql server 2012). I am trying to create the new team project inside a project collection that already have other seven team projects. I get the following error while creating team project inside this existing collection (But if I try to new create a team project in default collection, it works without error):

```
*Tf30177: Team Project Creation Failed.
TF30170: The plugin Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.WorkItemTracking failed during task WITs from group WorkItemTracking.  
Explanation 
Plugin error text: “Work item type validation failed. The operation cannot be completed.”  
User Action 
Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.*
```

When I looked into the project creation log, I have this exception details:

```
*2014-03-10T13:55:45 | Module: Work Item Tracking | Thread: 16 | Uploading work item type from file 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\3\TPW_tmpCF50.tmp\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Task.xml'...
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2014-03-10T13:55:45
Module: Work Item Tracking
Exception Message: TF26038: Field type for Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate does not match the existing type. It was Integer, but now is Double. (type ProvisionValidationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ClientMetadataProvisioningHelper.ThrowValidationException(String message)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.Provision.UpdatePackageField.Update(XmlElement fieldElement)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.Provision.UpdatePackageFieldCollection.ProcessFieldDefinitions(UpdatePackageRuleContext context, XmlElement fieldsNode, UpdatePackage batch)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.Provision.WITImporter.Translate()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Provision.ProvisionClass.Submit(ActionType action, Snapshot snapshot, Int32 projectId, WITImporter importer)
--- end Exception entry ---*

Could anyone please suggest how to solve this issue? Please let me know if you need more deitails on this error.
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally it worked. I edited devenv.exe.config file as mentioned in one of the link. I modified the following area in config file:

```
<runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

disabling the CAS security policy made it work; i.e., I updated the config file with **false** flag.

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="false" />
```

Now I am able to create the team project without error!

Comment: what link do you refer to in your first sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear (to me): the Collection where you are trying to create the new project has already defined the Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate field, and it's an Integer type.

One solution could be: exporting the Agile 6.2 template, search for that field, find that is defined to be a Double, revert back to Integer, import the patched template with a new name, create the project with the patched template.

Comment: Hi Guilio, Your answer was intact! but now an error in another point while creating team project, Could you see my answer to your post? Thanks in advance. /Jimmy